# Calculate shift for night and day

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have one table "commute_table" and i have 3 columns : ch_in enter PM , ch_out out AM, hours :

```
ch_in       ch_out       hours
19:28:35    01:00:00     05:32:00
19:15:54    01:00:00     05:45:00
19:30:08    01:00:00     05:30:00
```

and the total hours is wrong result from shift night to morning , what I tried to do is this query :

```
declare @stdt as datetime ,@enddt as datetime , @id INT ,@Timediff int ,@ch_num INT;
SET @id=1;
SET @ch_num=(SELECT count(*) FROM commute_table )
WHILE (@id <=@ch_num)

BEGIN

  SET @stdt=(SELECT log.ch_in from commute_table log where log.Cou=@id  )

    SET @enddt=(SELECT log.ch_out from commute_table log where log.Cou=@id )

 select @Timediff=datediff(mi,@stdt,@enddt)

update  commute_table  set  hours=(select   CONVERT(CHAR(8), DATEADD(MINUTE, @Timediff % 1440, '00:00'), 108)AS Timediff) where Cou=@id

 SET @id=@id+1  
    END
```

So what is the best way to calculate this shift and fasting ? Or what is  wrong in my query ?

The query is right i missed the calculation .

Comment: What is wrong with your query?

Comment: the result is wrong between : 19:28:35  -  01:00:00   =  05:32:00 hours the  right is 04:28:35

Comment: 7:30 pm to 1:00 am is 5 hours and 30 minutes.

Comment: Why is `04:28:35` correct? The time different *is* what your result set says. The better question, however, is why are you using a `WHILE` and performing the `UPDATE` RBAR?

Comment: to update the table mean this calculate right for all ?

Comment: Yes this is right i checked again .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that actually your understand of time is incorrect. There is *actually* 5 hours, 31 minutes and 25 seconds between the times `19:28:35` and `01:00:00`. If we break it down, firstly there are 31 minutes and 25 seconds to `20:00:00`. You then have a further 4 hours to midnight (`00:00:00`) and then finally another hour to `01:00:00`, giving a total time of `05:31:25`.

To answer the unasked question, however, of "This query performs very slowly, how can I improve it?" That is because you're using a `WHILE`. You would be much better off using a set-based solution. **Assuming** the values can never be 24 hours or more, then you could do something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE YourTable (ch_in time,
                        ch_out time,
                        [hours] time);

INSERT INTO YourTable (ch_in,ch_out)
VALUES('19:28:35','01:00:00'),
      ('19:15:54','01:00:00'),
      ('19:30:08','01:00:00');

GO


UPDATE YourTable
SET [hours] = CASE WHEN ch_in > ch_out THEN DATEADD(SECOND, DATEDIFF(SECOND,ch_in, ch_out),CONVERT(time,'00:00:00'))
                   ELSE DATEADD(SECOND, 86400 - DATEDIFF(SECOND,ch_out, ch_in),CONVERT(time,'00:00:00')) END; --86400 is how many seconds there are in a day
GO
SELECT *
FROM YourTable;
```

Personally, however, I would make `hours` a computed column:

```
ALTER TABLE YourTable DROP COLUMN hours;
GO
ALTER TABLE YourTable ADD [hours] AS CONVERT(time,(CASE WHEN ch_in > ch_out THEN DATEADD(SECOND, DATEDIFF(SECOND,ch_in, ch_out),CONVERT(time,'00:00:00'))
                                                        ELSE DATEADD(SECOND, 86400 - DATEDIFF(SECOND,ch_out, ch_in),CONVERT(time,'00:00:00')) END));

SELECT *
FROM YourTable;
```